# NetworkX asymmetric weights

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, networkx

Im using networkX to calcute all shortest path between endpoints.

In a example topology like graph1, in which weights are not symetric between R1 <-> R2, I would expect to see ONLY one shortest path from R1 to R3,
however I'm seeing two (see below). My goal is to replicate what protocols like OSPF or IS-IS does.

is there any way to achieve that ? (metrics/weights cannot be modified, are obtained directly from routers)

Example:

```
>>> from networkx import nx
>>> graph1 = {
...     
...     'R1':{'R2':{'weight':50000},'R3':{'weight':200}},
...     'R2':{'R1':{'weight':100},'R3':{'weight':100}},
...     'R3':{'R1':{'weight':200},'R2':{'weight':100}}
... }
>>> network_graph = nx.from_dict_of_dicts(graph1)
>>> print [p for p in 
nx.all_shortest_paths(network_graph,source='R1',target='R3', weight='weight')]
[['R1', 'R3'], ['R1', 'R2', 'R3']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default graph in networkx is not a directed graph (which is what a network which can have asymmetric edges is called), you need to specify that explicitly using:

```
network_graph = nx.from_dict_of_dicts(graph1, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

Which will lead to the proper answer:

```
print [p for p in nx.all_shortest_paths(network_graph,source='R1',target='R3',  weight='weight')]
 [['R1', 'R3']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer. Works fine !